# How do I manually initialize a Spring Boot repository without using beans or annotations? (Kotlin)

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to initialize a `repository` object in Spring Boot without having to make it a bean or an `Autowired` property.

I just want to do `feedRepository = FeedRepository()` in Kotlin. Why won't Spring Boot allow me to do this? Why does it have to be autowired or a bean?

here's my code:

```
@Component
class UriParser() {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var uriRepository: UriRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var hostRepository: HostRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var feedRepository: FeedRepository

    fun parseUri(uri: String) : Feed {
        val urlRepository = UriRepository()
        val uri = URI(uri)

        val uriRecord = uriRepository.save(Uri(scheme = uri.scheme, host = uri.host, port = uri.port))
        hostRepository.save(Host(host = uri.host))

        return feedRepository.save(Feed(uriId = uriRecord.id))
    }
}
```

Edit: ok so here's better context as to why I can't autowire things. Basically I'm doing this within a static function so I have absolutely no access to beans or autowired properties:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
     KafkaScheduler().init()
}
```

The Kafka scheduler basically executes several threads which all listen to kafka topics:

```
class KafkaScheduler() {
    // this doesn't work....
    @Autowired
    lateinit var feedRepository: FeedRepository

    fun init() {
        val threads = arrayOf(
            {
                QueueListener().init()
            },
            {
                PrefetchListener().init()
            },
            {
                FetchListener().init()
            }
        )

        val service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads.size)

        for (thread in threads) {
            service.submit(thread)
        }
    }
}
```

however, I can't autowire the KafkaScheduler class as a bean within a static method so I can't really make that a component or autowire any repositories, as far as I know.

Comment: Can you post the errors you are seeing?

Comment: yep, it's saying that uriRepository, feedRepository, etc. have not been initialized.

Comment: If you don't want DI (dependency injection) or IOC (inversion of control) then don't use Spring. Just use plain old Java. In your case you are overwriting a Spring controlled bean with a non Spring controlled bean. Depending on your implementation of the UriRepository this will not work. As it is a plain old java object and not a bean anymore.

Comment: Consider using constructor injection like `class UriParser(@Autowired val uriRepository...`

Comment: the problem is that I can't autowire stuff because I'm calling this all from a static function, so I have no access to any beans or spring's framework magic. i'll edit my answer for better context.

Comment: fair enough. i just need access to the repository (somehow) but like i said in the updated question this is all coming from a static method so there's no way to autowire the repositories like you usually would within a controller or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out. A simple `@PostConstruct` annotation solves everything I need for this. Essentially, I just mark `KafkaScheduler` as a `@Component`, autowire everything I need within it, the only difference is I added `@PostConstruct` to the init method so I have access to the autowired properties. Then I can autowire the repositories wherever I need them (in this case within `QueueListener` which uses `UriParser`)

```
@Component
class KafkaScheduler() {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var queueListener: QueueListener

    @Autowired
    lateinit var prefetchListener: PrefetchListener

    @Autowired
    lateinit var fetchListener: FetchListener

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        val threads = arrayOf(
            {
                queueListener.init()
            },
            {
                prefetchListener.init()
            },
            {
                fetchListener.init()
            }
        )

        val service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads.size)

        for (thread in threads) {
            service.submit(thread)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Noone stops you from initializing objects by yourself inside the spring managed component.

However, these objects:

- won't be managed by spring (e.g. if they also have dependencies you'll have to resolve them by yourself)
- It doesn't make sense to use `@Autowired` in this case because it works only between spring beans.

For example, this is wrong because class A is not managed by spring:

```
// not managed by spring
class A {
}

@Component
class B {
  @Autowired 
  A a;
}
```

So I believe you aim for something like this:

```
@Component 
class UriParser() { 

    // no autowired here, you manage everything by youself
    // also possible from constructor
    lateinit var uriRepository = UriRepository()
    ...
}
```

Side note, I haven't learnt Kotlin, so the syntax might be wrong.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you want to construct your own instance of a class, in this case a repository, you will have to manage your own database session, transaction and connection. Spring cannot help you out.

Comment: unfortunately i cant just use the UriRepository constructor since it's technically an interface of a spring boot repository.